# what's the differences between rake assets:precompile and RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

what's the differences between these two tasks, why i need to add RAILS_ENV=production when  cap deploy?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify `RAILS_ENV=production` environment variable so that your `config/environments/production.rb` configuration file is used when precompiling assets. It usually contains production configuration for assets pipeline:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.digest = true
```

If you omit `RAILS_ENV=production` then `development` configuration will be used (`config/environments/development.rb`).

Comment: so basicly run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile on local or productions, the files generated in public/assets should be the same ? can i sync them when deploy?

Comment: They may vary insignificantly based on what JavaScript runtime is installed locally and on server. Look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation) to get a better idea how to do local assets pre-compilation.

Comment: @Andrey Chernih 

Rails guides are missing stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

The first one will precompile your assets on your local dev box (development environment) and the other will precompile your assets on your production environment.  Your settings in your config files are most likely different and so it will go of what is configured off what is in the environment config for whatever you set `RAILS_ENV` to.

Answer (score 0):

Was going to write as a comment but too long...

--

**Production vs Local**

Something you also need to consider with this, is if you're precompiling for the `production` environment, it essentially compiles & configures your files *for* that environment

Simply, this means if you have any special conditions / dependencies for production only, using `RAILS_ENV=production` will use these over your local setup. This is why you'll have this setup in your `Gemfile`:

```
#Gemfile
group :production do
   gem 'xxxx'
end
```

--

`SHELL VARIABLES`

Something else you need to appreciate is `RAILS_ENV` is a [SHELL VARIABLE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-variables.htm). This means that whenever you run a `shell session` (I.E load `cmd`), these variables can be set to provide specific functionality.

In relation to `RAILS_ENV`, it means you'll be able to tell Rails to run in `production` mode for the time being; as opposed to running in `development`, `testing` or `staging` modes