# Difference between production and development version of precompiled assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

If I run `rails assets:precompile` locally without setting the `RAILS_ENV` to `production` **what is the difference in the output compared to if I ran the asset compile in the `production` environment?**

Because of some dev ops red tape I am running into - **I'm curious if I can get away with using development compiled assets in a production environment?**

Comment: explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029156/whats-the-differences-between-rake-assetsprecompile-and-rails-env-production-r

Comment: Thanks! I searched for awhile and somehow missed that.